# Oracle hierarchy query to exclude child records if parent is inactive

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

I have a table "MENUITEMS_TBL" with following structure (only showing needed columns)

```
MENU_ID                 NUMBER
PARENT_MENU_ID          NUMBER
MENU_TITLE              VARCHAR2(30)
ACTIVE                  VARCHAR2(1)        Possible values 'Y' (for active) and 'N' (for inactive)
```

This table is used to create a menu. I have written a hierarchy query to get the menu in right sequence, I have used hierarchy query to ensure that the depth is dynamic, and i do not have to change anything in case the level increase; till now following is the query that I have:

```
SELECT MENU_ID 
    , PARENT_MENU_ID 
    , MENU_TITLE 
    , ACTIVE 
FROM MENUITEMS_TBL
CONNECT BY PRIOR MENU_ID = PARENT_MENU_ID
START WITH PARENT_MENU_ID = 0
ORDER SIBLINGS BY PARENT_MENU_ID, MENU_ID
```

Issue is I can't figure out how to ensure that if any parent is 'N' (active field) then the child should also not be returned even if they are 'Y'.

If I try to put a condition that exclude all those where active is 'N' then it omits the parents only and I have orphan child records.

Need any suggestion on how I can achieve the desired outcome.

Thanks and Regards,

Saqib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by adding `WHERE active = 'Y'` condition together with `AND PRIOR ACTIVE = ACTIVE` condition added to the section for `CONNECT BY` clause :

```
 SELECT MENU_ID, PARENT_MENU_ID, MENU_TITLE, ACTIVE 
   FROM MENUITEMS_TBL
  WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'    
CONNECT BY PRIOR MENU_ID = PARENT_MENU_ID
       AND PRIOR ACTIVE = ACTIVE 
  START WITH PARENT_MENU_ID = 0
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY PARENT_MENU_ID, MENU_ID
```

Comment: Brilliant, I did not know that I could give another condition of PRIOR like so.I was hoping to try to bring the parent active column value in front of child to compare but this is superb